# Replace characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I am trying to replace all characters except last 4 in a String with *'s.
In objective-c there is a method in NSString class `replaceStringWithCharactersInRange: withString:` where I would give it range `(0,[string length]-4)` ) with string `@"*"`. This is what it does: 123456789ABCD is modified to *ABCD while I am looking to make ********ABCD. 
I understand that it replaced range I specified with string object. How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSError *error;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"*"];
```

Comment: Try `@"\d+"` as your `regularExpressionWithPattern:` argument. I tried `\\d+` on [this regex tester](http://regexpal.com/), and it failed, but `\d+` worked.

Comment: Fixed it. Just replace \\d+ with \\d in the pattern. Just remember that regular expressions require iOS 4 or later. If you need it to work in iOS 3, you should us NSScanner

Comment: The problem with the original is that `\d+` will greedily match every digit that it can, so they all become one match. Without the +, it matches individual digits, and thus replaces each one.

Comment: Your solution addresses his exact input (1-9, then ABCD), but it doesn't answer the question does it? Replace all characters in "a" NSString, not that specific NSString.. How is this an answer?

Comment: @JamesBoutcher Because the question is asking this. A question is not just the title.

Comment: @Lefteris - What about the _first sentence_ in the question?

Comment: @JamesBoutcher A programmer should know how to modify an answer and adjust to his needs. You can change both the regular expression and the range in the NSMakeRange to adjust to your needs. SO is for giving you guidelines, not to provide copy/paste code, which might end up being voodoo code, where you use it without knowing how it does work and why, which is the worst thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple problem... get the first part string and return it with the last four characters appended to it.
Here is a function that returns the needed string :

```
-(NSString *)neededStringWithString:(NSString *)aString {
    // if the string has less than or 4 characters, return nil
    if([aString length] <= 4) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSUInteger countOfCharToReplace = [aString length] - 4;
    NSString *firstPart = @"*";
    while(--countOfCharToReplace) {
        firstPart = [firstPart stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
    }
    // range for the last four
    NSRange lastFourRange = NSMakeRange([aString length] - 4, 4);
    // return the combined string
    return [firstPart stringByAppendingString:
            [aString substringWithRange:lastFourRange]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most unintuitive part in Cocoa is creating the repeating stars without some kind of awkward looping. `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:` allows you to create a repeating string of any length you like, so once you have that, here's a simple solution:

```
NSInteger starUpTo = [string length] - 4;
if (starUpTo > 0) {
    NSString *stars = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:starUpTo withString:@"*" startingAtIndex:0];
    return [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, starUpTo) withString:stars];
} else {
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the accepted answer was accepted, since it only works if everything but last 4 is a digit. Here's a simple way:

```
NSMutableString * str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"1234567890ABCD"];
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length] - 4);
[str1 replaceCharactersInRange:r withString:[[NSString string] stringByPaddingToLength:r.length withString:@"*" startingAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[theString substringToIndex:[theString length]-4]` to get the first part of the string and then combine [theString length]-4 *'s with the second part. Perhaps their is an easier way to do this..

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableString * str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"1234567890ABCD"];
[str1 replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length] - 4) withString:@"*"];
NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

it works

Comment: Did you actually read my question or copied answer from my question ? downvoted by me

Comment: NSMutableString * str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"1234567890ABCD"];
        NSRange replacementRange = NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length] - 4);
        NSMutableString * replacementString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    
        for (uint i = 0; i < replacementRange.length; i++) {
            [replacementString appendString:@"*"];
        }
        [str1 replaceCharactersInRange:replacementRange withString:replacementString];
        NSLog(@"%@",str1);

Comment: replaceCharactersInRange doesn't repeat the string -- it just replaces it. So you're taking all but the last 4 characters and replacing them with a single character of *, reducing the length of the string.

Answer (score -1):

The regexp didn't work on iOS7, but perhaps this helps:

```
- (NSString *)encryptString:(NSString *)pass {

    NSMutableString *secret = [NSMutableString new];

    for (int i=0; i<[pass length]; i++) {
        [secret appendString:@"*"];
    }

    return secret;
}
```

In your case you should stop replacing the last 4 characters. Bit crude, but gets the job done

Comment: All this does it return a string that's *'d out. How does this answer the question? (Leaving the last 4?)

Comment: Hmm indeed, didn't read well enough. 

 for (int i=0; i<[pass length] - 4; i++) {
        [secret appendString:@"*"];
    }

then use nsmakerange to copy the last 4 characters. But a better answer is already there